# Parsing every file in submap recursively to output folder whilst maintaining relativity

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm using the following batch code to convert all files in a certain directory if the target file doesn't already exist however I'm stuck at getting this to run through every submap and file within that (and keep the output relative with that submap)

So I currently use this:

```
for %%f in (input/textures/*.*) do ( IF NOT EXIST "ouput/textures/%%~nf.dds" (
"bin/ThempImageParser.exe" "input/textures/%%f" "ouput/textures/%%~nf.dds"
)
)
```

This works perfectly for a single folder (as was intended), it takes all the files in that specific folder, and passes them as arguments to my executable, which then outputs the file on the path of the second argument.

However this also contains a flaw (this is an additional problem though..) as it does not work if the output -folder- does not exist, so if possible I'd also want it to create the folder if need be.

I've found some batch documentation (I really don't have much experience with Batch) showing me a command called FORFILES and the /R parameter, however I couldn't adjust this so it'd keep the relative paths for the output too, it'd require string manipulation and I have no clue on how to do that.

So the result I'm after is something like this, it takes any file deeper than "input/textures/ for example:

```
input/textures/some/very/deep/submap/why/does/it/go/on/myfile.anyExtension
```

it should then take that file (and relative path) and basically change "input" with "output" and replace the file extension with .dds like this:

```
ouput/textures/some/very/deep/submap/why/does/it/go/on/myfile.dds
```

and pass those two strings to my executable.

Comment: What is a submap?  In the Windows world we use backslashes for paths.

Comment: submap/subfolder/subdir anything below a certain root folder is what I'd call that, sorry if I picked the wrong word for it.. 

Also it might be in batch, but for all the API's I've used (even typing into explorer itself) it doesn't really matter which slashes you'd use as it'll resolve them itself.

Comment: True for many things with the slashes but there are some Windows console commands that do fail with the forward slashes.  I can't recall which ones they are but it has has happened to me in the 20 plus years I have been writing batch files.

Comment: Just tested a few real quick. The `PUSHD` command will fail with `//servername/sharename`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir\wherever\something"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('xcopy /y /L /s "%sourcedir%\*"') DO (
 SET "destfile=%%a"
 SET "destfile=!destfile:*%sourcedir%=%destdir%!"
 IF /i "%%a" neq "!destfile!" (
  FOR %%m IN ("!destfile!") DO IF NOT EXIST "%%~dpm%%~na.dds" (
   ECHO MD "%%~dpm"
   ECHO "bin\ThempImageParser.exe" "%%a" "%%~dpm%%~na.dds"
  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

First, perform an `xcopy` with the `/L` option to list-only the individual fullnames of files that would be copied by the `xcopy`.

Assign each name found from `%%a` to `destfile`, then remove all characters before the source-directoryname from that filename, and replace that string with the destination directoryname.

This will yield the destination name for the file (with the original extension). The only exception will be the very last output line, which is a count-of-files report. Since this line will *not* contain the source directoryname, the replacement will not take place, so `%%a` will be the same as `!destfile!` - so we eliminate that.

Now assign the destination filename to a metavariable so we can select its various parts, and if the filename made from the destination drive and pathname, the name part of the original file and `.dds` does not exist, then make the destination directoryname and execute the imageparser, providing the desired output filename.

Note that these last two are `ECHO`ed instead of being executed for testing purposes. Remove the `ECHO`es to actually perform the command.

Note that `/` is a switch-indicator, `\` is a directory-separator.

Note that `MD` will report an error if the directory already exists. Append `2>nul` to the end of the `md` command to suppress that error message.

Comment: Wow this works perfectly thank you, this is way beyond what I could've come up with!